# IOS App Archive Failing - 2 errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have just added 64 bit support for my iPad app in Xcode. Before the update i was able to archive the app with no red errors. After i add `arm64` in the build settings get 2 error preventing the archive:

```
*ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/****/Documents/mApp/****/Pixate.framework/Pixate, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/****/Documents/mApp/****/Pixate.framework/Pixate (3 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Pixate", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in main.o
      objc-class-ref in BaseView.o
      objc-class-ref in BaseViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*
```

I have checked the framework and it is showing in the frameworks in the project.

I am currently using Xcode version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

Comment: Have you tried clean and build?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and I have also deleted the derived data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to third party framework `Pixate.framework`.
This framework is not built for arm64. That's why you got these errors.
How to fix it: find the version of this framework that was built with arm64 or just build it yourself by getting code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Pixate)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i suspected it was this framework as I had tried everything else.